# Which Perl facilities do I use to get all file names matching a pattern under a specific directory?

Tags: perl

I have a given directory name i.e `/root/share/ddlc` and it is a top directory, still have a few sub directories under `/ddlc`.

Now I would need to find all `temp.xml` files under `/ddlc` directory and copy it in an array.

Can you please suggest me a solution on how to do the same? I am new to Perl programming.

My question has some difference with the previous question. Here i need only temp.xml files and put it into an arry.

#### Input:

```
my @top_dir ='/root/share/ddlc'

/* find all temp.xml files under /root/share/ddlc  and store it in a array */
/* should have files name with complete path from current directory as below output */
```

#### Output:

Array should contain all text.xml names paths as below. These are just some sample file names.

```
my @result = {'core-data-types/text.xml','core-comm/text.xml', 'logger-api/text.xml'};
```

Comment: Try this module https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule

Comment: See also [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) and [How can I list files under a directory with a specific name pattern using Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707693/how-can-i-list-files-under-a-directory-with-a-specific-name-pattern-using-perl)

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Thank you for you response. 
For my requirement i want only specific file i.e. test.xml instead of listing all files. So can you please help me the solution